# How To Achieve Network Communication In HTML5 LibGDX/GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt, websocket, libgdx

**GOAL**: implement a basic client that can communication to a server from a LibGDX/GWT HTML5/JavaScript deployment. This is for a side-project multiplayer online browser-based game.

**WHAT I KNOW AND HAVE DONE**: All of my networking experience comes from KryoNet (create a server object, start the server, listen for requests, boom you're done) - can this (or a similar) architecture be achieved in a LibGDX/GWT HTML5 deployment?

After doing hours of research I have yet to have any luck with these magical things called "WebSockets" that everyone says to use. The only "WebSockets" I have found are in Gdx.net and they are "Not implemented".

[image]

The following code (that is executed in Libgdxclient-core and gets compiled from Libgdxclient-html)

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Net.Protocol;
import com.badlogic.gdx.net.Socket;


import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Net.Protocol;
import com.badlogic.gdx.net.Socket;


public class Client {
    private Socket socket;

    public Client() {
        Gdx.app.log("create()", "connecting.....");
        this.socket = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(Protocol.TCP, "127.168.1.1", 54555, null);
    }
}
```

Produces this output:

[image]

I came across a couple of GitHub repositories with regards to WebSocket implementation, however I'm stumped as to which (if any) of them is actually LibGDX/GWT compatible and could really use a hand as to what I need to read up on to accomplish my goal (I'm looking for a pure Java solution).

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer?  I want to do sockets in Libgdx for all platforms

Comment: You should be able to create an implementation with JSNI. This will take some classic Software Engineering, but will be a great exercise for you.

Answer (score 2):

You probably already resolved your problem (or chosen another solution), but it still might be useful for someone.

First of all: sockets in `Net` implementations are TCP sockets, which are not supported by browsers - hence the empty implementation. Even if you used a third-party GWT web sockets implementation, it would still be incompatible with LibGDX TCP server sockets.

However, you can choose one of many web socket server implementations along with Java-based web socket clients solutions for "standard" LibGDX platforms and GWT web sockets for the web. Common choices for LibGDX applications seem to be:

- [Java WebSockets](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) - server and client implementations. Client can target most regular LibGDX platforms.
- [gwt-websockets](https://github.com/sksamuel/gwt-websockets) - a very simple GWT wrapper of "native" browser web sockets.

These are some additional libraries that I recommend looking into:

- [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) - Android-compatible web socket client.
- [gwt-websockets](https://github.com/realityforge/gwt-websockets) from `realityforge` - more complex GWT web sockets wrapper packed with more features.
- [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/) - a superb server framework which features web sockets support.
- [gdx-websocket](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-lml/tree/master/websocket) - a common web sockets API for LibGDX application. Uses *nv-websocket-client* and custom GWT wrappers internally to target most LibGDX platforms. Disclaimer: I am the author.

Comment: How robust would you say these websocket implementations are? .. consistent enough to be used in commercial apps that require constant communication?

Comment: To be honest, I used LibGDX with web sockets only for small, personal projects, and haven't done any considerable benchmarking. Web sockets are basically using TCP, so they suffer the same limitations: unless you're making a turn-based game, [UDP communication would most likely do better](http://www.diffen.com/difference/TCP_vs_UDP). It would be best if you created some simple applications with each web socket library/framework and compare their performance. You can throw in the KryoNet too, so you can compare them with a UDP implementation.